# Mongodb in rails:Could not connect to a primary node for a replica

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to rails and mongodb. i have generated mongod model in my rails project name as Forum 
when i am trying to add record using following commands in rails console

```
f = Forum.new 
f.topic_name = "my_topic"
f.save
```

I am getting following error

```
Moped::Errors::ConnectionFailure: Could not connect to a primary node for replic
a set #<Moped::Cluster:25470936 @seeds=[<Moped::Node resolved_address=nil>]>
```

I am running mongod server on port 27017 
following is my mongoid.yml file

```
development:
  # Configure available database sessions. (required)
  sessions:
    # Defines the default session. (required)
    default:
      # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
      # (required).
      database: local
      # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
      # of host:port pairs. (required)
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        # Change the default write concern. (default = { w: 1 })
        # write:
        # w: 1

        # Change the default consistency model to primary, secondary.
        # 'secondary' will send reads to secondaries, 'primary' sends everything
        # to master. (default: primary)
        # read: secondary_preferred

        # How many times Moped should attempt to retry an operation after
        # failure. (default: 30)
        # max_retries: 30

        # The time in seconds that Moped should wait before retrying an
        # operation on failure. (default: 1)
        # retry_interval: 1
  # Configure Mongoid specific options. (optional)
  options:
    # Includes the root model name in json serialization. (default: false)
    # include_root_in_json: false

    # Include the _type field in serializaion. (default: false)
    # include_type_for_serialization: false

    # Preload all models in development, needed when models use
    # inheritance. (default: false)
    # preload_models: false

    # Protect id and type from mass assignment. (default: true)
    # protect_sensitive_fields: true

    # Raise an error when performing a #find and the document is not found.
    # (default: true)
    # raise_not_found_error: true

    # Raise an error when defining a scope with the same name as an
    # existing method. (default: false)
    # scope_overwrite_exception: false

    # Use Active Support's time zone in conversions. (default: true)
    # use_activesupport_time_zone: true

    # Ensure all times are UTC in the app side. (default: false)
    # use_utc: false
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: local
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read: primary
        # In the test environment we lower the retries and retry interval to
        # low amounts for fast failures.
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

what to do??

Comment: please give mongoid.yml also in question for better understanding of situation...

Comment: abhas: i have added mongoid.yml, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

review the localhost map in your hosts file or try hosts as `0.0.0.0:27017`.

Information about host file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)